# Ansible local configuration file not recognizing key?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I have a `vagrant` box with `precise32` up and running.

I am in `~/Workspace/vagrans/ansible` folder where there is a file `ansible.cfg` with the following entries:

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./dms/dev
private_key_file = /home/pkaramol/Workspace/vagrans/vagrant/precise32/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

This works:

```
ansible -m ping all --private-key=/home/pkaramol/Workspace/vagrans/vagrant/precise32/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -u vagrant
tsrv1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

This doesn't:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/testplay.yml 

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [tsrv1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
tsrv1                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Here is the playbook:

```
- hosts: testservers
  tasks:
    - name: just pinging
      ping:
```

And here is the inventory file

```
[testservers]
tsrv1
```

I must be missing sth (?) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to split the credentials between the configuration file and the playbook like [you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41467600/2947502).

You can use [`remote-user`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#remote-user) parameter in the `ansible.cfg` next to the `private_key_file`:

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./dms/dev
remote-user = vagrant
private_key_file = /home/pkaramol/Workspace/vagrans/vagrant/precise32/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

Comment: Accepting your answer as more efficient than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to set the `remote_user` explicitly in the playbook to `vagrant`

```
- hosts: testservers
  remote_user: vagrant
  tasks:
    - name: just pinging
      ping:
```